# How can I offer default values for SwiftUI config but let the user override them?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have created a SwiftUI chart and have used a dictionary to hold colours that are used within the view:

```swift
let ChartColors: [String: Color] = [
    "title": Color.white,
    "timeAgo": Color.red,
    ...
]
```

In my `struct`'s `body` variable I can use these like:

```swift
struct Chart: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("5min ago")
            .foregroundColor(ChartColors["timeAgo"])
        
    }
}
```

What is the best way to allow me to customise these dictionary values in a parent view, whilst also keeping these *default* values in the Chart view in case I don't want to change them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a struct for your colors (and provide default values):

```
struct ChartColors {
    var title = Color.white
    var timeAgo = Color.red
}
```

and then use it in your views:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let chartColors = ChartColors(title: .black, timeAgo: .green)
        return VStack {
            Chart(chartColors: chartColors) // with overridden colors
            Chart() // with default colors
        }
    }
}

struct Chart: View {
    var chartColors = ChartColors()

    var body: some View {
        Text("5min ago")
            .foregroundColor(chartColors.timeAgo)
    }
}
```